# ExtJS 3.3.0 disable save button until combobox has value

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using ExtJS 3.3.0 and I want to disable the save button until there is a value in the combo box.

I'm creating the combo box like so;

```
new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    id: this.idName + 'Combo_StateID',
    name: 'StateID',
    fieldLabel: 'State',
    singleOnly: true,
    typeAhead: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    store: StateStore,
    mode: 'remote',
    valueField: 'StateID',
    hiddenField: 'StateID',
    displayField: 'StateNumber',
    lazyInit: false,
    listClass: 'x-combo-list-small',
    tpl: '<tpl for=\".\"><div class=\"x-combo-list-item\"><span style=\"width: 50px;\">#{StateNumber}</span></div></tpl>',
}), " ) . "
```

I'm simply creating the button like so;

```
newPanel.addButton(
    {   
        iconCls:'icon-ok',
        text: 'Save Data'
    }
)
```

This all works fine. but disabling the button I can't figure out at all.

I have tried the following, but still nothing;

```
listeners: {
afterrender: function() {
  if (this.getValue() === null) {
    Ext.getCmp('yourButton').setDisabled(true);
      }
   else {
       Ext.getCmp('yourButton').setDisabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use if (this.getValue() === "") because getValue() returns empty string if no value is set.

Answer (score 0):

> As you have used **[afterrender](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-event-afterrender)** it will Fires after the component rendering is finished.

Try to use **select** method of [ExtJS Combobox](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-event-select)

I have created an demo. You check here how it is working [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2798)

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var PanelMain = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
            title: 'My Panel',
            initComponent: function () {
                Ext.applyIf(this, {
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'combo',
                        typeAhead: true,
                        triggerAction: 'all',
                        lazyRender: true,
                        mode: 'local',
                        store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                            id: 0,
                            fields: [
                                'myId',
                                'displayText'
                            ],
                            data: [
                                [1, 'item1'],
                                [2, 'item2']
                            ]
                        }),
                        valueField: 'myId',
                        displayField: 'displayText',
                        editable: false,
                        listeners: {
                            select: function (combo, record) {
                                Ext.getCmp('saveButton').setDisabled(false);
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        id: 'saveButton',
                        iconCls: 'icon-ok',
                        disabled: true,
                        text: 'Save Data',
                        handler: function () {
                            //here you can put your logic..
                        }
                    }]
                });
                PanelMain.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
            }
        }),
        panel = new PanelMain({
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

});
```